# Inheritance with EF Core (TPH). Large amount of columns and indexes

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

What is a good inheritance strategy when using ef core? Currently we have a abstract BaseEntity class with the primarykey, a created and modified date and some fields about the creator.
5 abstract classes inherit from this BaseEntity and over a 80 classes extend those abstract classes.
The result is a giant BaseEntity table where we are now facing the limits of the number of indexes on our mysql table (64 indexes).
For each fk we get an index. And iam a bit worried about the performance of this giant table. If we store like 10 Country objects in this table and like 1 billion citizens. Would my query GetAllCountries suffer from all does non country object in the same table? (our discriminators are bytes)

We could change our model but that would be a quite expensive one and feels weird since we use our abstract classes a lot in for example ICollections. We even have some many to one relations with our BaseEntity. For example an ActionHistory Item contains a BaseEntity.

We could recompile our database (mariadb) and change the max number of indexes to 128. Feels bad to.

Or we could change from table strategy (tpt) . But then we need a different orm. Since Ef core is only supporting Table per hierarchy. Quite expensive. And i have no idea what this will do with performance.

I am hoping that we are doing something terribly wrong in our model or fluent api configuration. Cause i could not imagine that all larger ef core projects are facing this problem.

Comment: Don't map the base classes. EF shouldn't know about them.

Comment: There is no good EF Core solution so far. As @Gert mentioned, the best is to not map the base classes as entities. But that is impossible if they are used in navigation properties. So you have to revisit/fix that in the model as well.